# Blazor session state with redis

Tags: session-state, blazor-server-side

I've been trying to add Blazor server-side pages to my asp.net core project. It's impossible due to the session state management. In-memory session variables are lost sometimes when calling a blazor page from a cshtml.

If I change to IDistributedCache with Redis, and session variables are stored in Redis, is it possible then to keep session variables when jumping from cshtml to blazor page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be. I think you'd just need to use a session key to track the right info in Redis.

For example you could use a guid as a URL parameter as the key, and use that to query Redis. Or you could use a client side cookie which you read out of the request and pass that down as a parameter to the blazor component. Really it depends on your setup as to exactly how this could work.